# Call an operator from inside a different operator and still show the redo/adjust panel

Tags: python

An artist at my studio requested a custom operator that would essentially be a ‘smart operator’ on a single hotkey that does different things depending on some specific contexts. this is easy to do, obviously- the problem is that when you call an operator in this way the redo panel for that operator doesn’t show up. I was hoping there was an INVOKE flag that would tell Blender that this was the operator call that needed the redo panel but I’m not finding anything.

anybody know of a trick to make this happen, or is this guy SOL? And in case you’re wondering- it’s not as simple as just setting a hotkey for different modes, because the contexts we’re checking for are more specific than that, ie) if edges are selected, do this- if faces are selected, do that.

FYI: cross-posted at blender-artists

Answer (score 2):

[kaio got me sorted out](https://blenderartists.org/t/call-an-operator-from-inside-a-different-operator-and-still-show-the-redo-adjust-panel/1338054/2). For anyone searching and finding this- you've got to make sure your 'switchboard' operator doesn't have an UNDO/REGISTER bl_option of its own, and when you call the other operator set the undo flag ([third operator class option](https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bpy.ops.html#calling-operators)) to True.